# What is the "manifest blob unknown: blob unknown to registry" error

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to push a multi-arch docker image to docker hub and run into errors (opened docker issue at https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/3100):

```
❯ docker build -t andig/evcc:latest-amd64 -f linux-amd64-.Dockerfile .
❯ docker build -t andig/evcc:latest-arm.v6 -f linux-arm-6.Dockerfile .
❯ docker push andig/evcc:latest-amd64
❯ docker push andig/evcc:latest-arm.v6
❯ docker manifest create --amend andig/evcc:latest andig/evcc:latest-amd64 andig/evcc:latest-arm.v6
❯ docker manifest annotate andig/evcc:latest andig/evcc:latest-amd64 --os=linux --arch=amd64
❯ docker manifest annotate andig/evcc:latest andig/evcc:latest-arm.v6 --os=linux --arch=arm --variant=v6
❯ docker manifest push andig/evcc:latest

failed to put manifest docker.io/andig/evcc:latest: errors:
manifest blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
manifest blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
manifest blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
manifest blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
manifest blob unknown: blob unknown to registry
```

Searching around shows error might be related to "foreign layers" (https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11865) but it's unclear how that might happen building an image based on Alpine.

As the docker github ticket and a forum question didn't get any response- what else could I do for further analysis? E.g., how could I find out which layer it's complaining about?

Comment: It errors when pushing the manifest, not the image.

Comment: @andig Can you look at this [link](https://github.com/slimsag/mega/blob/f68f39f4fc4229a542a554bd3f7c765973512d51/docker/vendor/src/github.com/docker/distribution/registry/api/v2/errors.go#L127-L135) will help you in digging into the problem

Comment: @MehantKammakomati the base image is Alpine from the same registry. Where should any "foreign" layer come from? It might help to delete the manifest from the registry but the cli doesn't seem to offer this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I suspected a problem with a somehow corrupted manifest that I might have pushed to docker hub I've started retrying the process with a clean, local registry. Following the steps led me to the same error message.

At this stage I've started another round of googling which not only suggested to use `--purge` for cleaning the manifest locally (which didn't help with this issue) but also to remove the local manifest cache by deleting `~/.docker/manifests`.

After removing the manifests folder both registry pushes- local and docker hub- started working.

Comment: I don't even have the `~/.docker/manifests` folder and also my CI doesn't have it. Any other suggestions what I can try? I'm getting the same error as you

Comment: Hi @David , I have the same error in my ci. Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should try the [buildx](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/multi-arch/) feature of CLI.

Let's say the `Dockerfile` is as below:

```
FROM alpine
ARG TARGETPLATFORM
ARG TARGETOS
ARG TARGETARCH
ARG TARGETVARIANT

ARG BUILDPLATFORM
ARG BUILDOS
ARG BUILDARCH
ARG BUILDVARIANT

RUN echo "Image target platform details :: "
RUN echo "TARGETPLATFORM    : $TARGETPLATFORM"
RUN echo "TARGETOS          : $TARGETOS"
RUN echo "TARGETARCH        : $TARGETARCH"
RUN echo "TARGETVARIANT     : $TARGETVARIANT"

RUN echo "Image build platform details :: "
RUN echo "BUILDPLATFORM     : $BUILDPLATFORM"
RUN echo "BUILDOS           : $BUILDOS"
RUN echo "BUILDARCH         : $BUILDARCH"
RUN echo "BUILDVARIANT      : $BUILDVARIANT"
```

docker build command -

`docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t sujaypillai/multiarc:latest --push .`

1. The --platform flag informs buildx to generate Linux images for AMD 64-bit, Arm 64-bit, and Armv7 architectures.
2. The --push flag generates a multi-arch manifest and pushes all the images to Docker Hub.

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v7 -t sujaypillai/multiarc:latest --push .
[+] Building 78.1s (40/40) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                     
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                                                                                   14.1s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                                                                13.3s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_meetupbuilder0                                                                                                                           0.7s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 618B                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [linux/arm/v7 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                     25.9s
 => [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                      28.4s
 => [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                      21.8s
 => [linux/amd64  1/11] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321                                                     13.2s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321                                                                    0.0s
 => => sha256:a24bb4013296f61e89ba57005a7b3e52274d8edd3ae2077d04395f806b63d83e 1.51kB / 1.51kB                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321 1.64kB / 1.64kB                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:a15790640a6690aa1730c38cf0a440e2aa44aaca9b0e8931a9f2b0d7cc90fd65 528B / 528B                                                                                         0.0s
 => => sha256:df20fa9351a15782c64e6dddb2d4a6f50bf6d3688060a34c4014b0d9a752eb4c 2.80MB / 2.80MB                                                                                     6.4s
 => => unpacking docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321                                                                  0.1s
 => [linux/arm64  1/11] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321                                                     11.8s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321                                                                    0.0s
 => => sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321 1.64kB / 1.64kB                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:3b3f647d2d99cac772ed64c4791e5d9b750dd5fe0b25db653ec4976f7b72837c 528B / 528B                                                                                         0.0s
 => => sha256:b538f80385f9b48122e3da068c932a96ea5018afa3c7be79da00437414bd18cd 2.71MB / 2.71MB                                                                                     6.9s
 => => sha256:62ee0e9f84408099149bdf3873554feebd1ee199daa1e0e80b840414cd5c4c9b 1.51kB / 1.51kB                                                                                     0.0s
 => => unpacking docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321                                                                  0.1s
 => [linux/arm/v7  1/11] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321                                                    13.6s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321                                                                    0.0s
 => => sha256:52278dd8e57993669c5b72a9620e89bebdc098f2af2379caaa8945f7403f77a2 2.41MB / 2.41MB                                                                                     8.2s
 => => sha256:7e4bece93b3e57b41f44ed293874207984d801979836c7aa4f8e9ef079f5283c 1.51kB / 1.51kB                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321 1.64kB / 1.64kB                                                                                     0.0s
 => => sha256:c929c5ca1d3f793bfdd2c6d6d9210e2530f1184c0f488f514f1bb8080bb1e82b 528B / 528B                                                                                         0.0s
 => => unpacking docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:185518070891758909c9f839cf4ca393ee977ac378609f700f60a771a2dfe321                                                                  0.1s
 => [linux/arm64  2/11] RUN echo "Image target platform details :: "                                                                                                               0.2s
 => [linux/arm64  3/11] RUN echo "TARGETPLATFORM    : linux/arm64"                                                                                                                 0.2s
 => [linux/arm64  4/11] RUN echo "TARGETOS          : linux"                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => [linux/arm64  5/11] RUN echo "TARGETARCH        : arm64"                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => [linux/arm64  6/11] RUN echo "TARGETVARIANT     : "                                                                                                                            0.1s
 => [linux/arm64  7/11] RUN echo "Image build platform details :: "                                                                                                                0.2s
 => [linux/arm64  8/11] RUN echo "BUILDPLATFORM     : linux/amd64"                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => [linux/arm64  9/11] RUN echo "BUILDOS           : linux"                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => [linux/arm64 10/11] RUN echo "BUILDARCH         : amd64"                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => [linux/arm64 11/11] RUN echo "BUILDVARIANT      : "                                                                                                                            0.2s
 => [linux/amd64  2/11] RUN echo "Image target platform details :: "                                                                                                               0.1s
 => [linux/amd64  3/11] RUN echo "TARGETPLATFORM    : linux/amd64"                                                                                                                 0.2s
 => [linux/amd64  4/11] RUN echo "TARGETOS          : linux"                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => [linux/arm/v7  2/11] RUN echo "Image target platform details :: "                                                                                                              0.2s
 => [linux/amd64  5/11] RUN echo "TARGETARCH        : amd64"                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => [linux/arm/v7  3/11] RUN echo "TARGETPLATFORM    : linux/arm/v7"                                                                                                               0.2s
 => [linux/amd64  6/11] RUN echo "TARGETVARIANT     : "                                                                                                                            0.1s
 => [linux/arm/v7  4/11] RUN echo "TARGETOS          : linux"                                                                                                                      0.1s
 => [linux/amd64  7/11] RUN echo "Image build platform details :: "                                                                                                                0.2s
 => [linux/arm/v7  5/11] RUN echo "TARGETARCH        : arm"                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => [linux/amd64  8/11] RUN echo "BUILDPLATFORM     : linux/amd64"                                                                                                                 0.2s
 => [linux/arm/v7  6/11] RUN echo "TARGETVARIANT     : v7"                                                                                                                         0.1s
 => [linux/amd64  9/11] RUN echo "BUILDOS           : linux"                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => [linux/arm/v7  7/11] RUN echo "Image build platform details :: "                                                                                                               0.2s
 => [linux/amd64 10/11] RUN echo "BUILDARCH         : amd64"                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => [linux/arm/v7  8/11] RUN echo "BUILDPLATFORM     : linux/amd64"                                                                                                                0.2s
 => [linux/amd64 11/11] RUN echo "BUILDVARIANT      : "                                                                                                                            0.1s
 => [linux/arm/v7  9/11] RUN echo "BUILDOS           : linux"                                                                                                                      0.1s
 => [linux/arm/v7 10/11] RUN echo "BUILDARCH         : amd64"                                                                                                                      0.1s
 => [linux/arm/v7 11/11] RUN echo "BUILDVARIANT      : "                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                            20.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                            0.6s
 => => exporting manifest sha256:df3e6c4fbf6641d1ecf860e05f7a796c44a0e2ada4f329a5d010ca57fd3e1c7a                                                                                  0.0s
 => => exporting config sha256:2fa9e2f9dd38e963f3c62c529169029407436c2a33b438b1e5c9f40a93987100                                                                                    0.0s
 => => exporting manifest sha256:b98e4b137e0966c9b67545facdc0ed481490e611faea202678274ad20f5e7b33                                                                                  0.0s
 => => exporting config sha256:b90679defbecf0b6e3335bf84928bf71b7cd3a161db67aa2f68e0101a752ca5a                                                                                    0.0s
 => => exporting manifest sha256:226daa79f5944d1df4a5265f56fd84f59fa53a4c7add722c9572d9abbb6c21db                                                                                  0.0s
 => => exporting config sha256:61bf5fa0b01de86509cb10eaa833c9ec9231f9983e0abae99e9d0912580e951e                                                                                    0.0s
 => => exporting manifest list sha256:995c492146ccd338fee877395543b4e756a583d670b9721d53724eb5f093d54f                                                                             0.0s
 => => pushing layers                                                                                                                                                              8.2s
 => => pushing manifest for docker.io/sujaypillai/multiarc:latest                                                                                                                 11.4s
```

Here is the result for `docker manifest` command -

```
docker manifest inspect docker.io/sujaypillai/multiarc:latest   | jq .manifests[].platform
{
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "os": "linux"
}
{
  "architecture": "arm64",
  "os": "linux"
}
{
  "architecture": "arm",
  "os": "linux",
  "variant": "v7"
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in building the image or annotating the manifest. The problem is in pushing the image to the registry and the actual error message is created by the registry. Nevertheless awarded bounty for bringing up buildx with example.